# Get a combined list of filenames and their md5sums

Tags: linux, bash, md5sum

I have a list of files listed 1 per line on some filein.txt like so:

```
mikesfile.php
ericsfile.php
subdir1/johnsfile.php
subdir1/davidsfile.php
subdir1/subdir2/ashleysfile.php
subdir1/subdir2/zoesfile.php
```

I need my bash script to read from that line by line, md5sum the corresponding files, and then write the file as well as its md5 on a new file named fileout.txt

For example:

```
e14086108b4d5d191c22b0a085694e4a - mikesfile.php
ebadb70de710217a7d4d4c9d114b8145 - ericsfile.php
b40bb5dfb23bf89b3011ff82d9cb0b0b - subdir1/johnsfile.php
d03e9b7306cb1f6c019b574437f54db0 - subdir1/davidsfile.php
f840a8d2ea7342303c807b6cb6339fd1 - subdir1/subdir2/ashleysfile.php
3560e05d5ccdad6900a5dfed1a4a8154 - subdir1/subdir2/zoesfile.php
```

I've been messing around with this:

```
while read line; do echo -n "$line" | md5sum; done; < filein > fileout
```

But it just dumps the md5 hash and completely omits the corresponding filenames. Searched all over trying to remedy this to no avail.

I'd very much appreciate your help in combining the two and properly writing them to the output file as shown. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: `xargs md5sum < filein.txt` should do the job

Comment: You are amazing. Thank you so much. God bless!

Comment: @user9331490, `xargs md5sum < filein` will throw errors like `md5sum: mikesfile.php: No such file or directory ...` if the input file lists filenames which are not in the current directory

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest What do you expect it to do other than that?

Comment: @glglgl, it's not "expecting" as you supposed, it's a statement

Comment: @user9331490 To be exact: do you want the MD5 sums of the files, i. e. their content, or the names?

Comment: @glglgl Content. Reason of the MD5'ing in the first place is integrity checking/change detection.

Comment: @user9331490 Thank you for this reply. In this case, many of the answers are wrong, as is your example, because your version calculates the MD5 of the file paths, not the contents of the files.

Answer (score 0):

**`bash`** + **`awk`** solution:

```
while read -r fn; do
    echo "$fn" | md5sum | awk -v fn="$fn" '{ print $0,fn }'
done < filein > fileout
```

---

```
$ cat fileout
1db757c4f098cebf93639f00e55bc88d  - mikesfile.php
f063a35599d453721ada5d0c8fcc0185  - ericsfile.php
a8c3a721d12b432c94c23d463fb5a93f  - subdir1/johnsfile.php
a4aa114d977c75153aac382574229d3a  - subdir1/davidsfile.php
abd77236c393266115acda48ddb4f9a0  - subdir1/subdir2/ashleysfile.php
18ba7e37f42a837d33a7fb3e56a618b5  - subdir1/subdir2/zoesfile.php
```

Comment: AFAICT, this gives you the MD5 sums of the file names, not the files.

Comment: @glglgl, that's obvious: let the OP answer your last comment-question - if he needs md5sum for contents - I'll delete my answer

Comment: Yes. First, I saw that your ansver provides that and only later I saw that the question is amiguous.

Answer (score 0):

Just a straight application of `md5sum` and `printf` will do it for you, e.g.

```
$ while read -r name; do 
    printf "%s %s %s\n" $(md5sum <<<"$name") "$name";
done <filein.txt
```

**Output**

```
1db757c4f098cebf93639f00e55bc88d - mikesfile.php
f063a35599d453721ada5d0c8fcc0185 - ericsfile.php
a8c3a721d12b432c94c23d463fb5a93f - subdir1/johnsfile.php
a4aa114d977c75153aac382574229d3a - subdir1/davidsfile.php
abd77236c393266115acda48ddb4f9a0 - subdir1/subdir2/ashleysfile.php
18ba7e37f42a837d33a7fb3e56a618b5 - subdir1/subdir2/zoesfile.php
```